# How to find the class from my variable got created in python multiple/multilevel inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Was having a code with multilevel inheritence. Finally I saw my  'self' is having an attribute 'uuid'. Since there are multiple inheritance, I am not able to find from where this  attribute got assigned. Is there any way to find it?

example :

My class is class A, it inherits from class B and  class C, each class again inherits from different. The chain is long. Just checking if I can achieve my ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read the documentation of the classes that I assume you imported from a different library.

You **might** be able to find it by walking the mro of the class and inspecting the signatures.  **If** the id is not assigned automatically, one of the signatures should have it.

```
from inspect import signature, getmro
for class_ in getmro(my_instance.__class__):
    print('{}: {}'.format(class_, signature(class_).parameters)
```

If you don't need to instantiate subclasses with parameters, or you can figure out which parameters to instantiate each class with, then you can create instances of each class and print the class of any instance that has `uuid`. The last class printed should be your the one you're looking for:

```
for class_ in getmro(my_instance.__class__):
    dummy_instance = class_()  # if the subclasses need parameters, you'll have to figure that out here.
    if hasattr(dummy_instance, 'uuid'):
        print(class_)
```